# File.listFiles crashes for invalid UTF-8 characters

Tags: android, file

The App crashed while navigating files within directory. crash log as follows:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf6
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'Test Color.X7��37meaba'

java.io.File.list(File.java:742)
java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:784)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sign the apk before running for this case to avoid crash.

Comment: As a safe workaround is perfect. I can delete the file that generates the problem, but for developers in countries with other encodings, this can be a nightmare!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I just wiped the emulator's data to continue with the development and tried not to add files with non-ascii characters.

Comment: sounds insane, why should I sign if I still developing my app?

Comment: As mentioned by Tano deleting files will make yourself tired and bored. Signing APK is relief for you.

Comment: @GaneshKanna..why unsigned apk is crashing..what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

If this happens for files OUTSIDE (not bundled in) your apk, just test on a real device. For me the emulator was causing the issue.